# How to Select multiple queries in PHP to MySQL

Tags: php

This query works when I run in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `ip` LIKE '1.1.1.1';
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `ip` LIKE '2.2.2.2'
```

But when I run this PHP code, it does not work:

```
<?php
require('configuration.php');

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `ip` LIKE '1.1.1.1';
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `ip` LIKE '2.2.2.2'";

$sql = $query;
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "ID: " . $row["id"]. "<br>IP:" . $row["dedicatedip"]. "<br><br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

This is the error I see in Apache:

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in /home/user/connect.php on line 17
```

To clarify, line 17 starts with:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
```

I do not know PHP a lot, but I tried to solve by searching but I failed.

Comment: you have to run each query separately or make the two queries one, your php code will not execute two separate queries at the same time

Comment: If you send two queries at the same time to the database server, you need to use multi_query() and not query().

Comment: @LelioFaieta could you send me a link for this?

Comment: @lukas.j I tried `multi_query` but got the same error

Comment: You need to adapt your code, since you receive more than one result set back from the server. Check [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: @Saeed You can use UNION statement of mysql.

Comment: Or simply: SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `ip` = '1.1.1.1' OR  `ip` = '2.2.2.2'

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Retrieve a single result set where any of the two conditions match?

Comment: @NicoHaase I wanted to extract all IPs in the table only (there are many other rows that I do not need them at the moment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve the problem with Mysql UNION statement.

```
$query = "(SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `ip` LIKE '1.1.1.1') UNION (SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `ip` LIKE '2.2.2.2')";
```

Comment: There is no need for a UNION. Also LIKE is the wrong operator as the whole field content is compared the equal operator = will do.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a UNION statement. This also works:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ip IN ('1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2')
```